# Trouble with Core Data dates

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsdate

I've got a Core Data model set up, with two entities in a one-to-many relationship (Items, and for each item, there can be multiple ResetDates). I'm pretty confident the model is set up correctly.

I can add new Items, and when doing so, add a new ResetDate (using the current date, with `[NSDate date]`). I can retrieve and display Items. What I'm having trouble with is retrieving and displaying the ResetDates.

**Updated**: It works now, thanks very much to the answerers below. Here's the code in question:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"resetDate" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:&sortDescriptor count:1];

NSMutableArray *sortedResets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[item.resets allObjects]];
[sortedResets sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSDate *oldDate = [[sortedResets lastObject] resetDate];
if ( !oldDate ) {
    oldDate = [NSDate date];
}

NSInteger numberOfDays = [self timeIntervalWithStartDate:oldDate withEndDate:currentDate];  // This function works fine, when given two NSDate objects

daysSinceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d days", numberOfDays];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `NSArray -objectAtIndex:` is not returning `nil` if you pass it an index that is out of the bounds, it will raise an `NSRangeException`, when you're not sure about the index, and need to use `-objectAtIndex:`, you have to call the `-count` method before to check.

More importantly, an `NSArray` can't contain a `nil` value, as `nil` is not an object.

Then, no, it's not an `NSDate` object, when you ask `item` for it's resets relationship (`item.resets`), you get an `NSSet` that contain `Reset` managed objects in return, not `NSDate` objects, what you want is the `resetDate` attribute of the returned `Reset` managed objects, maybe something like this :

```
// NSArray -lastObject method return nil if the array is empty
// Sending messages to nil is Ok there, so we can call resetDate directly

NSDate *oldDate = [[sortedResets lastObject] resetDate];
if ( !oldDate ) {
    oldDate = [NSDate date];
}
```

Hope that help, and that my English is understandable...

Comment: Ahhhhh, okay, okay. That makes *much* more sense now -- it's a `Reset` object, not an `NSDate`. One problem: `resetDate` is a `@property` of the `Reset` class, not a method. I'm not terribly good with the syntax on these things yet... tried `[[sortedResets lastObject].resetDate]`, but that clearly isn't what I'm looking for...

Comment: @Triz since `resetDate` is declared as an `@property`, your Reset object *will* have `resetDate` and `setResetDate:` methods.  That's the whole point of the `@property` syntax.

Comment: @Dave: Right, okay. I'm getting a warning on that line, though, that there's no `resetDate` method declared. I've got it in the `Reset` class header, as `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *resetDate;`, and in the implementation as `@dynamic resetDate;`. Should it be `@synthesize` instead of `@dynamic`? The latter is how the CoreData template I started with was doing things, so I kept it.

Comment: Interestingly, the code works perfectly right now, despite that warning... Would like to get rid of it anyway, though. :)

Comment: Warning remedied by `#include`ing the Reset class. Yay!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe replacing :

```
NSDate *oldDate = sortedResets[0];
```

with :

```
NSDate *oldDate = [sortedResets objectAtIndex:0];
```

will help. sortedResets is an NSArray object, not a C array ;)

Comment: I'd also recommend replacing the `initWithObjects:count:` method to create the sortDescriptors array with the simpler `initWithObject:` method.

Comment: Dave: This (`NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObject:sortDescriptor];`) doesn't work -- am I missing something?

Comment: Brian: Thanks for that, I forget sometimes that I'm not in C any more :)

I think that gets me a lot closer, but now I'm getting crashes when a new Item is being created, and this gets called to display the newly-created row, but there isn't anything at index 0 yet. I thought the `if() {}` I inserted above should help, but it still dies. Any ideas?

Comment: @Triz - whoops, there's no `initWithObject:` method. You can use `+[NSArray arrayWithObject:]` and then not have to worry about releasing the sortDescriptors array.